# Xcode 4 test build class conflict

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

Hey all, I'm new to Xcode/Cocoa/Objective C and have an annoying issue I can't seem to track down. I've got a program with a handful of classes and a set of unit tests built in with the Xcode "include unit tests" option checked when I created the project. For the most part, everything works fine, but when I run my tests I see the following error:

> objc[12505]: Class [class foo] is
>   implemented in both
>   /Users/[me]/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/1F5222ED-0A3C-41BC-AFA3-CB8FC744EFCE/[app
>   name].app/[app name] and
>   /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[app
>   name]-eumytpkyfitihadpqeyxjpwapxoa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/[app
>   name]Tests.octest/[app name]Tests.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Looking at the logs for the build of the test target shows that Xcode is compiling [class foo] for the test target, but none of the other classes that the testing program uses (apologies if my terminology is incorrect).

The top of my [app name]Tests.m file is the following:

```
#import "[app name]Tests.h

#import "[class x].h"
#import "[class y].h"
#import "[class z].h"
#import "[class a].h"
#import "[class foo].h"
```

[app name]Tests.m uses all of the above classes, with [class foo] having no real significance that I can think of, except maybe that it was created first.
I've tried moving the `#import "[class foo].h"` declaration around with no change.
I've tried renaming [class foo], cleaning the product, and rebuilding with no change.

Looking at the files in Finder, all the program classes are in the root directory for [app name] and only the two test files are in the root directory for [app name]Tests, which I believe is as it should be.

Often running the tests will actually work, even with this error, but sometimes it won't or the breakpoints will perform unpredictably in [class foo], which is really annoying. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In summary, the solution was that apparently I had added [class foo].h and .m to both the app and testing targets when I made the project. Removing those files and re-adding them to just the app target fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, don't know if it solves your problem, but it seems that you have to rebuild your derived data folder.

I got some problems with classes of older projects after upgrading, too. I solved the problem by deleting the app from the simulator,  clean the project and go to the derivedData Folder at /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

You can remove the whole folder with your applications name. Xcode will rebuild it on its own.
Another method that works sometimes is to create a new project with Xcode 4 and move all files of your project to this new project.
This will make sure that you ain't get problems with the updated projectsettings in Xcode4.

Comment: To be precise, this is not an imported old project, I started from scratch with Xcode 4.
I tried recreating the project as you suggested but I ended up with a bunch of Mach linker errors. I'm guessing I did something wrong. The results of that effort made me notice how you can specify targets in the "add existing files to project" dialog. I removed [class foo].h and .m from my original project and re-added them and it appears to work fine now. No idea why I didn't think of that before.
Although not precisely correct, your answer did lead me to the solution so you get the accept :)

Comment: I have the same issue. Cleaning, deleting DerivedData and resetting the sim had no effect.